# How do I search for a certain attribute in mysql JSON?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I can use this mysql query to search for all rows where attribute 'color' is Red

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(`attribute`,'$.color') = 'Red'
```

I can use this mysql query to search for all rows where attribute 'color' is not Red

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(`attribute`,'$.color') != 'Red'
```

But how do I search for all rows where attribute 'color' is found regardless of color?
And how do I search for all rows where attribute 'color' is not found?

Comment: Pay attention: both provided solutions will work on single-level JSON only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use next queries:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(`attribute`,'$.color') IS NULL ;

SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(`attribute`,'$.color') IS NOT NULL ;
```

[fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=f571f0c0def9f63e97809b9a8b5cb598&php_version=null&sql_version=mariadb)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT val, JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_KEYS(val), '"color"')
FROM test
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4b353a36457cc0636fc42511681a9828)

Also you may simply search the value using common string functions (like `LOCATE('"color"', json_column)`).